# Status of WMF image support in iText

Tags: java, itext7

What is the status of WMF file support in itext 7?

It is listed as supported file and in class ImageDataFactory it is listed as private final field, but in method isSupportedType and in createImageInstance it isn't used.

I use html2pdf module, my template is in HTML and I need to use method that is supported in HTML 2 PDF conversion.

I need to use some vector type and WMF is my choice since it doesn't support SVG (without rewriting them to PNG).

I find it problematic, especially that in older versions and in LibrePDF fork of older iText it works correctly.

Comment: That is not a technical question that can be answered on Stack Overflow. You should ask questions about supported features to iText Software directly. See https://itextpdf.com/support for contact information.

Comment: According to the Rules of Stack Overflow, iText Software is not allowed to answer that question here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support for the reason why.

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks for information